# Remove alert from a javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've the below code from a tutorial,i want the action but i just want to remove the alert,

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('read()', 10000);

function read()
{
FB.api('/me/news.reads' + 
'?article=<?php echo $fbrdurl ?>&access_token=<?php echo $access_token ?>','post',
function(response) {
var msg = 'Error occured';
if (!response || response.error) {
if (response.error) {
msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
}
alert(msg);
} 
else {
alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
}
</script>
```

I've tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('read()', 10000);

function read()
{
FB.api('/me/news.reads' + 
'?article=<?php echo $fbrdurl ?>&access_token=<?php echo $access_token ?>','post';
}
</script>
```

but not worked, thanks

Comment: Did you know you can get rid of `eval()`? Instead of `setTimeout('read()', 10000)` just do `setTimeout(read, 10000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is just to ignore the response (remove the alert dialogs):

```
function read()
{
  FB.api('/me/news.reads' + 
  '?article=<?php echo $fbrdurl ?>&access_token=<?php echo $access_token ?>','post',
   function(response) {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the alert() function anywhere else, you can simply override it so it does nothing:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```